# Mutating list while making multiple replacements in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, mutable

I have a csv file with one column which has following data in a test.csv file

```
3 0JKT02 CX85d
3 0JNAd0 CP80d
3 0KAAd0 CT894
3 0KAAd0 CT895
3 0LARd0 CL003
3 0JNA10 CL80d
3 0JNA20 CL80d
3 0JNA30 CL80d
3 0JNA40 CL80d
3 0FAK3e CL00v
3 0FAK3e CT00e
```

what I want to do is to replace all the small cap (d, e and v) with instances. Here

```
d = [1,2,3,4]
e = [1,2]
v = [3,4]
```

So to take example of last two items, I need to get 
`3 0FAK31 CL003`, `3 0FAK32 CT003`, `3 0FAK31 CL004`, `3 0FAK32 CT004`.

I have declared an array with all the old values in them, I loop through this array and update it one by one, because it mutates, i'm not getting my expected results. It seems it skips after 'remove' code and just screws up the list. Plus it still has e and v variable in the 'oldarray'. I'm frustrated, please help. Also if you can critic my code and suggest more pythonic way of doin it, I would appreciate it. Here is the code...

```
class Compare:
    def __init__(self):
        f1 = open('test.csv','r')
        self.oldarray = []
        for row1 in f1:
            self.oldarray.append(row1.strip('\n').strip())  
        self.dict1 = {'d':[1,2,3,4],'e':['1','2'], 'v':['3','4']}

    def work(self,key,values):
        for item in self.oldarray:
            if key in item:
                for each in values:
                    self.oldarray.append(item.replace(key,each))
                self.oldarray.remove(item)        

    def do(self):
        for key,values in self.dict1.items():
            self.work(key,values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import csv
    x = Compare()
    x.do()
    for i in x.oldarray:
        print i
```

Comment: Odd design. Use plain functions and variables for this.

Comment: Yes I didn't need an OOP design but I'm trying to learn that. Normally I would have done functions only.

Comment: Use OOP when you need it, don't use it everywhere. If youre learning then this is a rather poor example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider using a generator** Instead of mutating the list while iterating over it, a pythonic approach is to write a function that takes in one sequence and yields another sequence. You can take in a sequence of lines and then yield one *or more* lines for each input line based on your substitutions. This would only take one function, not a class.

**Your "extra" variables are being left in because you're only doing one `replace()` at a time.** It sounds like you want to *permute* the combinations of available letters for replacement, so if both `e` and `v` are present you should end up with 4 rows output. Here is a self-contained example of how you could use `itertools.product` to address this, as I don't think you're going to get there as easily with loops.

```python
import itertools
mapping = {'d':[1,2,3,4],'e':['1','2'], 'v':['3','4']}
line = "3 0FAK3e CL00v"
subs = (
    [(key, value) for value in mapping[key]]
    for key in mapping
    if key in line
    )
for combination in itertools.product(*subs):
    lineb = line
    for letter, number in combination:
        lineb = lineb.replace(str(letter), str(number))
    print lineb
```

**If you care about result order, don't use a dict or sort a secondary data structure**. Dicts have arbitrary ordering of keys.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it works ! However, I know my approach was not Pythonic but I'm surprised why it doesn't work !!! Each new element that I add by 'append' get's added in the end so why does it not work ?? It just bugs the hell out of me that it doesn't work despite my logic being right. Anyway you can tweak my approach and make it work ? I'm not hung up on OOP approach but on logic.

Comment: Try writing a simple loop over a list that removes the current element and then prints the list. Each time you remove an item the other items "shift" over so your loop ends up skipping items. That's why it's not a good idea to remove items from a list you're iterating over. Or if you have to, loop backward.